# Join function in CloudFormation template in YAML not working as expected

Tags: powershell, yaml, aws-cloudformation

As a part of my CloudFormation template I use in AWS, I am creating a local PS1 file to join server to domain.

```
'c:\cfn\joindomain.ps1':
  content: !Join
    - ''
    - - $ServerNamePS = "
      - !Ref ServerName
      - |
        "
      - $UserPS = "
      - !Ref Domain
      - \
      - !Ref DomainUser
      - |
        "
      - $PassPS = ConvertTo-SecureString "
      - !Ref DomainPass
      - |
        " -AsPlainText -Force
      - |
      - $DomainCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserPS, $PassPS
      - |
      - $DomainPS = "
      - !Ref Domain
      - |
        "
      - $DomainOU = "
      - !FindInMap 
        - OUTempComputer
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - !Ref NetbiosDomain
      - |
        "
      - |
        echo "Joining server $ServerNamePS to domain $DomainPS with user $UserPS"
      - |
        if (!(Get-ADComputer $ServerNamePS -Server (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service "GlobalCatalog" -DomainName $DomainPS).HostName[0] -Credential $DomainCred)) {Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainPS -Credential $DomainCred -ouPath $DomainOU -Restart -Force}
```

As a result on created server, I get this PowerShell file c:\cfn\joindomain.ps1:

```
$ServerNamePS = "TST-SRV"
$UserPS = "locdom.com\ad.joiner"
$PassPS = ConvertTo-SecureString "123456" -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserPS, $PassPS$DomainPS = "locdom.com"
$DomainOU = "OU=AWS,DC=locdom,DC=com"
echo "Joining server $ServerNamePS to domain $DomainPS with user $UserPS"
if (!(Get-ADComputer $ServerNamePS -Server (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service "GlobalCatalog" -DomainName $DomainPS).HostName[0] -Credential $DomainCred)) {Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainPS -Credential $DomainCred -ouPath $DomainOU -Restart -Force}
```

If you take a look at the line 4 in resulting PS1 file, you can see there is no new line between PassPS and DomainPS variables (`"$PassPS$DomainPS"`).

How can I ensure there is a new line in given YAML syntax between those 2 variables? Obviously I am not using "|" correctly.

Thank you very much!

Thanks to @lexicore's suggestion, this is and updated working solution:

```
    'c:\cfn\joindomain.ps1':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          $ServerNamePS = "${ServerName}"
          $UserPS = "${Domain}\${DomainUser}"
          $PassPS = ConvertTo-SecureString "${DomainPass}" -AsPlainText -Force
          $DomainCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserPS, $PassPS
          $DomainPS = "${Domain}"
          $DomainOU = "${DomainOU}"
          echo "Joining server $ServerNamePS to domain $DomainPS with user $UserPS"
          $DomainGC = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service "GlobalCatalog" -DomainName $DomainPS).HostName[0]
          try {Get-ADComputer $ServerNamePS -Server $DomainGC -Credential $DomainCred -ErrorAction Stop}
          catch {Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainPS -Credential $DomainCred -ouPath $DomainOU -Restart -Force}
        - {
          DomainOU: !FindInMap [OUTempComputer, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref NetbiosDomain]
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I'd suggest replacing `!Join` with `!Sub`.
Something along the lines:

```
content: !Sub
  - |-
    $ServerNamePS = "${ServerName}"
    $UserPS = "${Domain}\${DomainUser}"
    ...
```

We've found `!Sub` much easier to handle that `!Join`.

Comment: It works! I will add the working syntax as an answer. Thank you @lexicore